# Number Theory Problem: Find a perfect power k^m > 1 where k, m, k^m do not contain 2 in their decimal digits, nor do share any decimal digit.

Tags: number-theory, perfect-powers

Find a perfect power k^m > 1 where k, m, k^m do not contain 2 in their decimal digits, nor do share any decimal digit, even if k^m might possibly be expressed in more than one way for some value, e.g. 8^2 = 4^3. I do not know if such an integer exists at all, or how many and how large they are if they do. Perfect powers exist with all the other individual decimal digits d missing from the otherwise also not decimal digit sharing k, m, and k^m. So, d = 2 seems to be elusive, or, is indeed the exception?
Examples for each d not equal 2 as follows:
For d = 0 -> 2^3 = 8; for d = 1 -> 3^2 = 9; for d = 3 -> 67^2 = 4489; for d = 4 -> 33^2 = 1089; for d = 5 -> 2^4 = 4^2 = 16; for d = 6 -> 7^2 = 49; for d = 7 -> 44^2 = 1936; for d = 8 -> 34^2 = 1156; and for d = 9 -> 38^2 = 1444.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: At least $3^4=81$. Minimum possible $k$, minimum possible $m$ for this $k$

Comment: Thank you, but sorry, no good. 3^4 = 9^2 = 81, and 2 as an exponent is forbidden.

Comment: If $k^m=l^n$, where one of $l$ and $n$ contain 2 or share decimal, this case is prohibited?

Comment: Yes, prohibited, as stipulated. I used an online big integer calculator to search and soon the numbers grew very large. The chances of finding such number diminished.

Comment: Then $m$ is odd and $k$ can end only on $3$ or $7$. I believe there is no way to find such number (if exists) except brute-force. I've checked all numbers $(10m+5\pm2)^{4k+3}$ for $0\leq m,k \leq 300$. No success.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ivan. Exactly what I thought: maybe brute force search could bring up one or more such integer. Else, an insightful proof may be found to confirm the possibility, even the infinitude, of such numbers. Conversely, the impossibility, therefore their non-existence could be proven. It fascinates me but I cannot do anything about it.